# How to write $\sin(x_1).\sin(x_2)$ as an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

We know that $\sin(x)$ is the same as writing $\int_{0}^3 \cos(x)dx$.

However, I am interested if there is a similar way to write $\sin(3). \sin(4) $ as an integral.

One way I think is $$\sin(3).\sin(4) \Longrightarrow  \int_{0}^3 \cos(x)dx.\int_{0}^4 \cos(y)dy $$
However, it is not so satisfying.
Please help me to know some other way to write $\sin(3).\sin(4)$ (or, in general, $\sin(x_1).\sin(x_2)$) as an integral.
 Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\sin(x_1)\sin(x_2) &= \frac12 \left( \cos (x_1-x_2) - \cos(x_1+x_2\right)\\
&=\frac12 \int_{x_1+x_2}^{x_1-x_2} -\sin(t) \, dt \\
&=\frac12 \int_{x_1-x_2}^{x_1+x_2} \sin(t) \, dt \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$$\sin x_1 \sin x_2 = \frac12(\cos (x_1-x_2) - \cos (x_1+x_2))$$

Hence we have:

$$\int_{x_1-x_2}^{x_1+x_2}\frac{\sin x}2 dx = \frac12(\cos (x_1-x_2) - \cos (x_1+x_2))=\sin x_1 \sin x_2$$